# PHP output to command line

Tags: php

I start my script from command line and it outputs things as they happen but a week ago it stopped outputing and now outputs everything when script finishes. I have ob_start() but as I know this does not effect command line output.

Comment: Can you please post that core part of the script here? Which version of PHP and on what environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove ob_start()... try this code on the command line, and it will print the text all at once:

```
<?
ob_start();
echo "test\n";
sleep(10);
echo "buffer\n";
?>
```

Comment: I thought that ob_star() does not function in command line but it really does, this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to do it is to create a function in php like this:

```
function console_log($message) {
    $STDERR = fopen("php://stderr", "w");
              fwrite($STDERR, "\n".$message."\n\n");
              fclose($STDERR);
}
```

where $message is the desired output to command line. Then simply call the function wherever you would like to output and pass in whatever you want it to print.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be very helpful if you could post your script here, at least the relevant parts, but things I'd test are:

- Did you turn on buffering?
- Are you running the process in something like a nohup or something else that may be buffering it?
- Did you change any other buffering settings?

Outputting only at the end of the script seems a buffering problem.